# Multi touch water ripple WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, pixelsense

I want to create Multi touch water ripple effect in  Surface Application. I am using  shader library to create ripple. But It create only one ripple at a time. I Want to make it multi Ripples/ Water simulation   type Animation in my Application.

Answer (score -1):

Multi touch in WPF  is kinda tricky. It doesnt offer very high level options.

You are going to have to deal with the [**ManipulationStarting**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarting.aspx), **ManipulationStarted**, **ManipulationDelta**, **ManipulationInertiaStarted**, **ManipulationBoundaryFeedback** and **ManipulationCompleted** events.

Also have a look at this "[**IsSingleTouch**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationstartingeventargs.issingletouchenabled.aspx)" property that you should set on the manipulations.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898416.aspx) should also prove useful. I used it to do some basic Multitouch in a WPF application.

However, I cant help you with **Pixelsense**, so my answer may not be relevant at all.